# Create ajax call in plugin wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I found this [plugin](https://github.com/joshcummingsdesign/wp-plugin-starter/) to create plugin.

I got an issue, how do I make an ajax call? As the docs, I've created `plugin-name/includes/class-admin-ajax.php` and placed my `wp_ajax_` hook there, but seems like the hook is not recognized yet.

class-admin-ajax.php

```
<?php 
add_action('wp_ajax_test', 'test');
function test(){ die('yay'); }
```

javascript section

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('#submit').click(function () {
            var url = ajaxurl + "?action=test";
            $.get( url, function () {

            });
        })
    })
</script>
```

The ajax call always return 0. Seems like the `wp_ajax_test` is not registered yet. Can you point out where are my mistakes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Update]

So, I contacted the author, and he gave the answer after couple of days, here: https://github.com/joshcummingsdesign/wp-plugin-starter/issues/17